# Generating reversible permutations over a set

Tags: function, permutation, algebra, bijection

I want to traverse all the elements in the set Q = [0, 2^16) in a non sequential manner. To do so I need a function f(x) Q --> Q which gives the order in which the set will be sorted. for example:

```
f(0) = 2345   
f(1) = 4364   
f(2) = 24   
(...)
```

To recover the order I would need the inverse function f'(x) Q --> Q which would output:

```
f(2345) = 0
f(4364) = 1
f(24) = 2
(...)
```

The function must be bijective, for each element of Q the function uniquely maps to another element of Q.

How can I generate such a function or are there any know functions that do this?

Comment: Note: You do not just need a permutation of Q. You need a [cyclic derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation); a permutation that has no fixed points and cannot be decomposed into multiple independent cycles.

Comment: ...oh, crud, I was thinking of `f(x)` as "what comes after x", but you probably thought of it as "what goes in position x".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: In the following answer, `f(x)` is "what comes after x", not "what goes in position x". For example, if your first number is 5, then f(5) is the next element, not f(1). In retrospect, you probably thought of f(x) as "what goes in position x". The function defined in this answer is *much* weaker if used as "what goes in position x".

---

[Linear congruential generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) fit your needs.

A linear congruential generator is defined by the equation

```
f(x) = a*x+c (mod m)
```

for some constants `a`, `c`, and `m`. In this case, `m = 65536`.

An LCG has full period (the property you want) if the following properties hold:

1. `c` and `m` are relatively prime.
2. `a-1` is divisible by all prime factors of `m`.
3. If `m` is a multiple of 4, `a-1` is a multiple of 4.

We'll go with `a = 5`, `c = 1`.

To invert an LCG, we solve for `f(x)` in terms of `x`:

```
x = (a^-1)*(f(x) - c) (mod m)
```

We can find the inverse of 5 mod 65536 by the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), or since we just need this one computation, we can plug it into Wolfram Alpha. The result is 52429.

Thus, we have

```
f(x) = (5*x + 1) % 65536
f^-1(x) = (52429 * (x - 1)) % 65536
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many approaches to solving this.

Since your set size is small, the requirement for generating the function and its inverse can simply be done via memory lookup.  So once you choose your permutation, you can store the forward and reverse directions in lookup tables.

One approach to creating a permutation is mapping out all elements in an array and then randomly swapping them "enough" times.  C code:

```
int f[PERM_SIZE], inv_f[PERM_SIZE];
int i;

// start out with identity permutation
for (i=0; i < PERM_SIZE; ++i) {
    f[i] = i;
    inv_f[i] = i;
}

// seed your random number generator
srand(SEED);

// look "enough" times, where we choose "enough" = size of array
for (i=0; i < PERM_SIZE; ++i) {
    int j, k;
    j = rand()%PERM_SIZE;
    k = rand()%PERM_SIZE;
    swap( &f[i], &f[j] );
}

// create inverse of f
for (i=0; i < PERM_SIZE; ++i)
    inv_f[f[i]] = i;
```

Enjoy

Comment: 2^16 is a small test case to play with. This solution becomes intractable fast as the problem size increases.

Comment: Sure, if you want something that is not limited to within the constraints that the problem was expressed, this is not it.  However, another option comes from cryptography.  Block ciphers are keyed bijective maps where both directions are easily computable to onw who knows the key.  There are many methods to construct them, but [Feistel ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) are a good starting place.  They will be "more random" than a LCG.  Each key corresponds to a different bijection (for well chosen function).